# Does any differentiable function admit an expansion $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_{n}x^{n}$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function in some interval $D$.

Then does that mean that we could always write f(x) in the form $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_{n}x^{n}$ in that interval?

Comment: I do not see why continuity suffices. If you are making a conjecture, can you provide some examples?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. You have $$x \longmapsto f(x)=\frac1x, \quad x \in D=(0,\infty),$$ which is **differentiable on the interval** $D$, but it **does not** admit a series expansion of the form $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_{n}x^{n}$ on $D$.

Comment: What if $n$ runs from $-\infty$ to $\infty$

Comment: @MrDi It is not sufficient...

Comment: @MrDi The function in the counter example is also differentiable...

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but could please explain to me what property or conditions must $f(x)$ have for it to be written as $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_{n}x^{n}$

Comment: @MrDi All analytic functions admit such an expansion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function

Comment: Ok, so if $f(x)$ was analytical in the interval $D$ then $f(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_{n}x^{n}$ is valid in $D$. Is That correct?

Comment: @MrDi The answer is yes. Thanks.